# How do I apply css to only IE 8 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want some of my styles to only be applied to IE 8 and lower. I also only want to change my style sheet and NOT my html. Is this possible?

Here is my style I want to apply to only IE 8 and lower (I don't want to change IE 9 or 10)

```
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
        background-color: #000000;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
        background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
        border-radius:  9px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
```

}

I only want the very last style to be used on IE 8 and lower

Comment: If you don't want to put some ugly hacks into your css, I'd suggest using IE conditional comments to include a IE-only stylesheet.

Comment: IE8 can't do much with that `-webkit-` property.

Comment: I had thought about making a new IE-only sheet but that seemed like a lot of work since I'd have to add a lot of conditional comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1:

```
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background-color: #000000\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4)\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png)\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    background-repeat: no-repeat\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    border-radius:  9px\9; /* IE8 and below */  
    filter: alpha(opacity=40)\9; /* IE8 and below */  
}
```

2:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
/*According to the conditional comment this is IE 6*/
  .ui-icon-searchfield:after {your stuff}
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
/*According to the conditional comment this is IE 7*/
  .ui-icon-searchfield:after {your stuff}
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
/*According to the conditional comment this is IE 8*/
  .ui-icon-searchfield:after {your stuff}
<![endif]-->
```

My suggest is the second(Conditionals)

Comment: could I add the \9 without adding anything to my html?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's one of the suggested methods.

Comment: like @sagibb said, you can do it without adding html, the first method  is css

Comment: I tried it but the styles are still being applied in IE 9. Should the number be an 8 instead?

Comment: @RDoolabh I personally prefer conditional comments over CSS hacks for two reasons: It allows you to store any browser specific CSS code in a separate CSS file, which is neater. when IE8 is dead you can just throw the reference from the HTML and keep your CSS code clean. Some older FF browsers might also catch up on some of the CSS hacks, which might make them render stuff different from what you desired. Just go with <!--[if lte IE 9]>Make <IE9 happy.<![endif]-->

Comment: for ie8 and below is \9, I recommend you should use the conditional instead

Comment: alright, I got it with option 1 eventually. It just seems that the '\9' only works with some css styles apparently. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It has all the information needed to work on IE CSS.

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/